# How to filter this type of data?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

If I have some numpy arrays like

- `a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])`
- `b = np.array([4,5,7,8])`
- `c = np.array([4,5])`

I need to combine these arrays without repeating a number. My expected output is `[1,2,3,4,5,7,8]`.

How do I combine them? Which function should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more approach you can give a try is using reduce from functools and union1d from numpy.
For eg -

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(np.union1d, (a, b,  c))
```

Output -

```
array([1,2,3,4,5,7,8])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `numpy.concatenate` with `numpy.unique`:

```
d = np.unique(np.concatenate((a,b,c)))

print(d)
```

Output:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 7 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has a datatype called [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

> A set is an unordered collection with no duplicate elements

The easiest way to create a set out of your array would be [unpacking your arrays](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments) into the set:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> b=np.array([4,5,7,8])
>>> c=np.array([4,5])
>>> {*a, *b, *c}
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8}
```

Please note, that the set is **unordered**. This is not the right answer for you, if the order of the elements in your array is important.

Comment: I am glad I could help you :)